# How to push view depending on the row selection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image]/*****UPDATED** ***/[image: Second Image][image]r.com/YH3cm.png

I am trying to figure out in the above image, how will we know if the user has selected Date or Track. 
/*UPDATED*/
The data I am receving is through a select query and I create an array to store the list. It is dynamic and not necessary limited to two fields, it can have 10 fields also. How will I know which row is selected and how will I push the data on to the next view.

Like in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, how should I push the date or track field on the next view?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (dvController == nil) 
  dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

Teat *obj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

dvController.obj = obj;
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not very clear what you're trying to do. If you want to push a certain view controller depending on what the content of the cell is, but there is no definite arrangement of the rows, I would use the row index to access the array that is the source of your data. Some very loose code:

```
WhateverObject* selectedObject= (WhateverObject*)[tableDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if( [selectedObject hasAnAttributeYouCareAbout] )
{
    MyViewController* theCorrectController= whicheverViewControllerYouWant;
    theCorrectController.anAttribute= aValue;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:theCorrectController animated:YES];
}
```

And here's how you can define your `UIViewController` subclass `MyViewController` with specific attributes. In the .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

     int anAttribute;
}

@property int anAttribute

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize anAttribute;

@end
```

You can have as many attributes as you want of whatever type, and then you can set them with `aViewController.anAttribute` as above.

Comment: Hi Luke,I have updated the description above.So when I select the first row, I get the date information with dates on the next page.I use a select query to get the information for the list.Now when I select the first date,it should push the date information with the other information to pull up the date information.To get the list of sessions,I create another select query to pull the inforamtion using the selected date.My main concern is how can I pass the information to another view to do a select query on that date variable.since I can only control which view to be passed and not the data.

Comment: To do that, I would subclass UIViewController with member variables for the data you'd like to store. In the if statement above, you could just set these as properties before you push the view controller.

Comment: oh..thanks but I am little newbie to this area. Is it possible for you to provide me with an example like how can I create a subclass UIViewController with member variables and set those as properties?

Comment: hey luke sorry dude had to cutoff from this place since was travelling for a while.thanks for the updates.but have quick question. whats the aValue in your code ?

Comment: It can be anything you want. Presumably it would be different within each 'if' statement.

Answer (score 0):

I fear it's not perfectly clear what do you want to do... if you need to push a different view depending on the selected row you may simply do something like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    //push view 1
else 
    //push view 2

}
```

UPDATE: calling `indexPath.row` you get the index of the selected row. I guess is up to you to decide what to do depending on what row is selected. To pass this information to the next view you may simply think of a `@property` field to set, a method to call or a custom init method for the view controller you are pushing. What is the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: I have updated my question. I do know I can use indexpath.row but lets say if its dynamic how will you push that data to the next view?

Comment: Updated the answer. I fear I cannot say more without knowing exactly what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

Create objects - dateInfoViewController and trackInfoViewController and then...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (row==0)
{
if (self.dateInfoViewController == nil)
     {
    DateInfoViewController *temp = [[DateInfoViewController alloc] init];
    self.dateInfoViewController = temp;
    [temp release];
    }



else {
    dateInfoViewController.title= [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sessionInfoDetailsArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    YourAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [delegate.sessionNavigationController pushViewController:dateInfoViewController animated:YES]; 
    }
}

  if (row==1)
{
    if (self.vetInfoViewController == nil)
    {
       TrackInfoViewController *temp = [[TrackInfoViewController alloc] init];
        self.trackInfoViewController = temp;
        [temp release];
    }


    else {
        trackInfoViewController.title= [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sessionInfoDetailsArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        YourAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        [delegate.sessionNavigationController pushViewController:trackInfoViewController animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the list is dynamic, it is not restrain to 1 or 2 or 3. It depends on the data and the length of the array. so in such a case, static definition of the row will not work. how can I come up with something which is dynamic and push the view controller correctly.

Comment: If the list is Dynamic, IT IS IMPOSSIBLE FOR YOU TO DYNAMICALLY CREATE NEW VIEWS FOR NEW ROWS. I am guessing that you would want to use the same rows.. this is the logic.

Comment: Actually, I have a query which pulls up the data from the DB and store in the table and I write a query to pull the data for the information. I also have similar query to pull the information for the next view depending on the date. but I need to know if the user has selected date as the row to call the correct query. how can I call the correct query wrt to the select row that then ?